# If $a+b+c+d = 2$, then $\frac{a^2}{(a^2+1)^2}+\frac{b^2}{(b^2+1)^2}+\frac{c^2}{(c^2+1)^2}+\frac{d^2}{(d^2+1)^2}\le \frac{16}{25}$

Tags: inequality

If  $a+b+c+d = 2$, prove that

$$\dfrac{a^2}{(a^2+1)^2}+\dfrac{b^2}{(b^2+1)^2}+\dfrac{c^2}{(c^2+1)^2}+\dfrac{d^2}{(d^2+1)^2}\le \dfrac{16}{25}$$

Also $a,b,c,d \ge 0$.

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: I haven't tried anything worth mentioning frankly. :)

Comment: Young's Inequality (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality) might be somehow useful, although I have not figured out how.

Comment: If you can prove $$\frac{a^2}{(a^2+1)^2}+\frac{b^2}{(b^2+1)^2}\le2 \frac{\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)^2‌​}{\left(\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)^2+1\right)^2}$$ for $1\le a+b\le2$ which is the same as $\frac{4a^2}{(4a^2+1)^2}+\frac{4b^2}{(4b^2+1)^2}\le\frac{2(a+b)^2}{((a+b)^2+1)^2‌​}$ for $\frac12\le a+b\le1$, then WLOG $b=c=d$ by repeated usage and continuity argument. This inequality is true, but I cannot prove it nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $0 \le a \le b \le c \le d$, with $a+b+c+d=2$,

Then $(48a-4)(a^2+1)^2-125a^2 = (2a-1)^2(12a^3+11a^2+32a - 4) \ge 0$, for $a \ge \frac{1}{8}$;

(See that $32a-4 \ge 0$ and $12a^3+11a^2$ is positive).

That is $\dfrac{a^2}{(a^2+1)^2} \le \dfrac{48a-4}{125}$, and similarly for $b,c,d$ and adding them we have $\sum\limits_{a,b,c,d} \dfrac{a^2}{(a^2+1)^2} \le \sum\limits_{a,b,c,d} \dfrac{48a-4}{125}=\dfrac{80}{125}=\dfrac{16}{25}$.

The case $a < \frac{1}{8}$,

We have $(540x + 108)(x^2+1)^2 - 2197x^2 = (3x-2)^2(60x^3+92x^2+216x+27) \ge 0$, for $x \ge 0$.

Thus $\sum\limits_{x \in \{b,c,d\}} \dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2} \le \sum\limits_{x \in \{b,c,d\}} \dfrac{540x+108}{2197}=\dfrac{108}{169}-\dfrac{540a}{2197}$

and, $\dfrac{a^2}{(a^2+1)^2} < a^2 < \dfrac{a}{8} < \dfrac{540a}{2197}$.

So, $\sum\limits_{a,b,c,d} \dfrac{a^2}{(a^2+1)^2} \le \dfrac{108}{169} < \dfrac{16}{25}$

Equality occurs iff $a=b=c=d=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Why does $$\sum\limits_{x \in \{b,c,d\}} \dfrac{540x+108}{2197}=\dfrac{108}{169}-\dfrac{540a}{2197}?$$ 
Shouldn't it be $$\sum\limits_{x \in \{b,c,d\}} \dfrac{540x+108}{2197}=\dfrac{324}{2197}-\dfrac{540a}{2197} \lt \dfrac{16}{25}-\dfrac{540a}{2197}$$

Also where did you get the insight for the equations you used?

Comment: @todestrieb It's correct $$\sum_{x\in\{b,c,d\}}\frac{540x+108}{2197}=\frac{540(b+c+d)+324}{2197}=\frac{54\!\!0(2-a)+324}{2197}=\frac{1404}{2197}-\frac{540a}{2197}=\frac{108}{169}-\frac{5\!\!40a}{2197}$$ As for the insight I think it's pretty clear he wanted to find linear estimates. That can take a little work, but with computers it's pretty easy to verify if you are correct.

Comment: You are both right. I am thinking of a generalization of this. Is the following true? $$\dfrac{x_1^2}{(x_1^2+1)^2}+\dfrac{x_2^2}{(x_2^2+1)^2}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\dfrac{x_n^2}{(x_n^2+1)^2}\le \dfrac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}$$ with $$x_1+x_2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+x_n= \sqrt{n}$$$$x_1,x_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,x_n \ge0$$$$ n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Comment: If you wish to answer go here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733675/inequality-with-x-1x-2-cdot-cdot-cdotx-n-sqrtn

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the function 
$$
\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} +
\frac{y^2}{(1+y^2)^2} +
\frac{z^2}{(1+z^2)^2} +
\frac{t^2}{(1+t^2)^2} +
\lambda(x+y+z+t-2)
$$and write the first order conditions:
$$
0 = -\frac{2x(x^2-1)}{(1+x^2)^3} + \lambda,
$$and the same equation for $y,z,t$. In particular,
$$
\frac{x(x^2-1)}{(1+x^2)^3} = \frac{y(y^2-1)}{(1+y^2)^3}
= \frac{z(z^2-1)}{(1+z^2)^3} = \frac{t(t^2-1)}{(1+t^2)^3}
$$

Taking a look at the [variations](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5B%7Bx%28x%5E2-1%29%7D%2F%7B%281%2Bx%5E2%29%5E3%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2C2%7D%5D) of this function,

[image]

we see that if $x\neq y$ then $x,y < 1$ and $x,y,z,t\in \{u,v\}$, with

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{u(u^2-1)}{(1+u^2)^3} = \frac{v(v^2-1)}{(1+v^2)^3} \\
u+v=1\\
u<v.
\end{cases}
$$
Then [an analysis](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bx%28x%5E2-1%29%7D%2F%7B%281%2Bx%5E2%29%5E3%7D+%3D+%7By%28y%5E2-1%29%7D%2F%7B%281%2By%5E2%29%5E3%7D%2C+x%2By%3D1)  proves that 
$(u,v) = (0,1)$:

[image]

Eventually, compute the two potential extrema:
$$
\frac{1^2}{(1+1^2)^2} + \frac{1^2}{(1+1^2)^2}+0+0 =\frac 12;\\
\frac{(1/2)^2}{(1+(1/2)^2)^2} + \frac{(1/2)^2}{(1+(1/2)^2)^2}+
\frac{(1/2)^2}{(1+(1/2)^2)^2} + \frac{(1/2)^2}{(1+(1/2)^2)^2} = \frac {16}{25}.
$$